# Why is the host name in the shell prompt "MacBook-2" instead of "MacBook"?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I opened Terminal on my MacBook Pro and the prompt reads:

```
MacBook-2:~ myName$
```

Is there something wrong? Do I need to be worried about this? Why `-2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because there can't be two devices on the network with the same name. MacBook becomes MacBook-1, then MacBook-2.

You can check this with:

```
scutil --get ComputerName
```

This could be because there are two other devices with the name MacBook, or because Bonjour hasn't forgotten that the device disconnected. It's nothing to worry about, and you can change the computer name from System Preferences → Sharing or use scutil to ask for a name change.

```
scutil --set ComputerName MacBook
```

Comment: You are quite optimistic about being able to change it back. Usually when the "stale" entry is there, you cannot rename it and will then get bumped to MacBook-3. I think there are several bugs that need fixing on Apple's end and a better handling of IPv4 and IPv6 dual network interface before we will get out of this renaming mess.

Comment: @bmike For the few times I've had this happen, I've never had a problem changing it back! :) I guess it depends on how the network is configured and how devices on the network respect specification and such.

Comment: Apple networking hardware seems to really get stuck for me. Also I have seen loops where Apple TV and such are up to (325) after their names!